# Round Down to the Nearest 10

Tags: r, rounding, floor

So I have a column of values ranging from 10 to 100 and I want all of them to be rounded to the nearest 10. The trick is I want it to always round down. For example, 55 would become 50 not 60. I imagine floor would be implemented for this but when I tried floor, it only returned the same value unaltered.

```
x
10
15
20
27
30
34
```

etc...

What I want:

```
x
10
10
20
20
30
30
```

What I tried:

```
data$x <- floor(data$x)
```

This only gave me the exact same values.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since `floor(x)` gets the smallest integer `y` not greater than `x`, you can divide all the values in `x` by ten, get the floor, then multiply back by ten; i.e., you can use `floor(x/10) * 10`

```
x <- c(10,
       15,
       20,
       27,
       30,
       34)
floor(x/10) * 10
# [1] 10 10 20 20 30 30
```

Answer (score 5):

You do not need floor here check with `%/%`

```
v%/%10*10
[1] 10 10 20 20 30 30
```

Comment: Works just as well. On a microbenchmarked sample `%/%` is a bit slower than `floor` (well about 50% slower), but both operations are so fast that it's hard to imagine a case where this would be the bottleneck. I'd encourage users to choose whichever they feel is most readable.

Comment: @Gregor thank you for timing ! :-)

Answer (score 4):

I'm late to the party on this, but I do have a similar solution which seems to run pretty fast. It is similar to the other options, but uses the `trunc` function.

```r
x<- c(10, 15, 20, 27, 30, 34)
trunc(x / 10) * 10
#> [1] 10 10 20 20 30 30
identical(x %/% 10 * 10, floor(x/10) * 10)
#> [1] TRUE
identical(trunc(x / 10) * 10, floor(x/10) * 10)
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2019-01-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

I have inflated the size of the `x` vector and run all three with `microbenchmark`. The `trunc` method is fastest on this data.

```r
set.seed(42)
x <- sample(x, size = 10000000, replace = TRUE)

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(trunc(x / 10) * 10,
               floor(x / 10) * 10, 
               x%/%10*10)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>              expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq
#>  trunc(x/10) * 10  55.89856  58.57783  66.08508  65.62727  71.74459
#>  floor(x/10) * 10  95.50139  99.18817 108.17770 108.10694 113.86548
#>       x%/%10 * 10 143.65839 150.77401 157.42086 158.56745 161.84987
#>        max neval
#>   95.49897   100
#>  147.47947   100
#>  188.56060   100
```

<sup>Created on 2019-01-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>